# Upload csv file to SQL Server from Excel VBA without declaring data type of Columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have a manual process in SQL Server that I would like to automate in Excel VBA. In MS SQL Server  2014, the task is to upload a csv file to a new table in a database. To do this, I right-click on the database that I want, click Tasks / Data Import. This opens up the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. In there, I choose Flat File Source as the Data Source. Then, I choose the csv file that I want. I tick the checkbox, “Column names in the first data row”. I click next, next and the file creates on the server.

Is there a way to do this from Excel VBA? I’m sure I can create the table in SQL from Excel VBA by passing across a CREATE TABLE command, and then execute a BULK INSERT command, which will pass the data across. However, I’d rather avoid the creation of the table as it would involve specifying the data types of the columns; when the process is invoked from SQL Server, SQL Server does that for you automatically. Can I also do that automatically from Excel VBA?

Comment: If you want to automate it, why not use SSIS?

Comment: @Larnu, can this be controlled / executed from Excel VBA? I am unfamiliar with SSIS.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest you do, although you *could*. Normally you would use the Agent or T-SQL to execute the task in the SSISDB.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (but probably not the best way) I can think of:

- Read the CSV file through Excel-VBA

[Excel VBA - How to read csv file line by line but not the whole file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969671/excel-vba-how-to-read-csv-file-line-by-line-but-not-the-whole-file)

- Write an `CREATE TABLE` query with the contents of the file. Define the columns as `[VARCHAR]`.

[Create a SQL Table from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927349/create-a-sql-table-from-excel-vba)

---

I have tried the process you describe with "SQL Server Import and Export Wizard" and I have created a table this way.

Then, after selecting the table and checking the "Script table as" > "CREATE IN", I have noticed the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Textdokument](
    ["name1"] [varchar](50) NULL,
    ["name2"] [varchar](50) NULL,
    ["name3"] [varchar](50) NULL,
    ["name4"] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Spalte 4] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Honestly, this is not very optimized, as far as I had some columns, which were numbers and `varchar` is quite "expensive" for them.

Comment: the table doesn't already exist in SQL though. I want to create it from Excel VBA without going to the trouble of specifying the data types of the fields.

Comment: @mediaeval - from VBA you can use any SQL command. `CREATE TABLE` is probably what you need.

Comment: @Vityata this smells like you're saying that the Excel file doesn't have a uniform format; is my assumption correct?

Comment: @Larnu - nope, excel has a uniform format, but the OP actually asks to create a table through SQL and automatically to assign the columns to the correct data type.

Comment: @Vityata, in the CREATE TABLE example that you posted, it also specifies the data types of the columns. I would like to avoid this, because there are approx 150 columns in my table. Is it possible to do it this way?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to actually tag the OP there, @Vityata; was aimed at them.

Comment: @mediaeval You can't `CREATE` a table without declaring the datatypes.

Comment: @mediaeval - I slowly start understanding what you are asking for... :) In general, I do not know... But, you can create a `BULK INSERT`  statement and see the SQL Statement which was used by SQL SERVER to create the table... It can be useful.

Comment: @Vityata, I have repeated what you did in SQL with "Script Table as". It's helpful. I had hoped it would be possible to replicate how it is done in SQL Server by not specifying the data types, but I do not think it is possible. If I could find a way to pass across the option, "Column names in the first data row” (there is a fuller explanation of this in the original post), that would be perfect.

Comment: @mediaeval - cool! Concerning the Column names in the first data row -  you can read the first row with VBA and write the names in the SQL CREATE TABLE command. It would be probably a bit tricky to do it the first time.